# Python filling string column "forward" and groupby attaching groupby result to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe looking generated by:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[100, ' tes  t  ', 3], [100, np.nan, 2], [101, ' test1', 3 ], [101,'   ', 4]])
```

It looks like

```
         0      1      2
     0  100    tes t   3
     1  100    NaN     2
     2  101   test1    3
     3  101            4
```

I would like to a fill column 1 "forward" with test and test1. I believe one approach would be to work with replacing whitespace by np.nan, but it is difficult since the words contain whitespace as well. I could also groupby column 0 and then use the first element of each group to fill forward. Could you provide me with some code for both alternatives I do not get it coded?

Additionally, I would like to add a column that contains the group means that is
the final dataframe should look like this

```
         0      1      2  3
     0  100   tes t    3  2.5
     1  100   tes t    2  2.5
     2  101   test1    3  3.5
     3  101   test1    4  3.5
```

Could you also please advice how to accomplish something like this?

Many thanks please let me know in case you need further information.

Comment: What do you mean by this: "I would like to a fill column 1 "forward" with test and test1"?

Comment: Hi, many thanks. I completed the final dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could use [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and then check if the stripped string is empty.
Then, perform `groupby` operations and filling the `Nans` by the method `ffill` and calculating the means using [`groupby.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) function as shown:

```
df[1] = df[1].str.strip().dropna().apply(lambda x: np.NaN if len(x) == 0 else x)

df[1] = df.groupby(0)[1].fillna(method='ffill')
df[3] = df.groupby(0)[2].transform(lambda x: x.mean())
df
```

[image]

Note: If you must forward fill `NaN` values with first element of that group, then you must do this:

```
df.groupby(0)[1].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.iloc[0]))
```

---

**Breakup of steps:**

Since we want to apply the function only on strings, we drop all the `NaN` values present before, else we would be getting the `TypeError` due to both floats and string elements present in the column and complains of float having no method as `len`.

```
df[1].str.strip().dropna()

0    tes  t    # operates only on indices where strings are present(empty strings included)
2     test1
3          
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

The reindexing part isn't a necessary step as it only computes on the indices where strings are present.

Also, the `reset_index(drop=True)` part was indeed unwanted as the groupby object returns a series after `fillna` which could be assigned back to column 1.

Comment: Dear Nickil, many thanks! In the first line, it seems to me that after dropna() we are working with a series of len 3. Could you explain how pandas can map this back to the original frame. Could you also explain what the second line does? In the third line, we could have employed fillna on the whole series, correct? Can you explain why you employed reset_index there? thx again!!

Comment: Appreciate your efforts in going through my answer and pointing out improvements in the techniques employed. Indeed, your speculations were right and really helped me simplify the answer further. Regarding the first line, I've added some explanation as to why it was necessary. All the best!

Comment: Dear Nickil, many thx again. I actually realized when going through the answer that your lines 2 and 3 are part of the basic functionality of groupby and very well documented on the help page. Sorry, for not knowing this. One last question:  df[1] = df[1].str.strip().dropna() is a valid operation because pandas matched df (on the left hand side) and the series on the right hand side by the common index values, is this true?

Comment: It's like when we drop the null values, we only get 3 elements as opposed to 4. We only operate on these 3 elements and all others are immediately assigned `NaN`. And do remember that `Nan` values are placed in these indices only. So, it doesn't matter and would not cause any indexing errors.